# Pythonic method to create 2 lists, one of which is a repeating set of strings and turn into a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have a list of 'widget types', ["C","A","B"] and need to make a dict for those types to correspond to their respective ID's, 1='C', 2='A', 3 = 'B', 4= 'C', 5='A', 6= 'B', 7 = 'C', etc.
I already know how to do it, I just wondered if there was a more elegant pythonic way of achieving it than that below, also it would be good to have the length of the dict/lists expandable, i.e. in the example it is 10 but in reality it would be many hundreds of widgets long.

**Existing working code**

```
wid_letter = ['C', 'A', 'B']
widgets_per_row = 10
wid_letter = wid_letter * widgets_per_row 
#print("wid_letter : ", wid_letter, '\n')



ID = (list(range(1,widgets_per_row  + 1,1)))
wid_type = []

# Make list of widget_letters to match length of widget ID
for i in ID:
    wid_type.append(wid_letter[i-1])
print(len(wid_type))

# Turn the two lists into a dict
wid_ID_dict = dict(zip(ID, wid_type))
print('\n'*2, wid_ID_dict,'\n')

print("Widget_type: ", wid_ID_dict[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wid = {i:w for i,w in enumerate(wid_letter[:widgets_per_row],1)}
```

Dict comprehension above may be your quest item, wid is wid_ID_dict in your code.

Comment: Note that this will result in `{1: 'C', 2: 'A', 3: 'B'}`, it will not work when `widgets_per_row` is larger than `wid_letter` is long.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overriding your list, you can just use `module` to get the index of letter you need. Then simple dictionary comprehension will do the job:

```
wid_letter = ['C', 'A', 'B']
widgets_per_row = 10

wid_ID_dict = {i + 1: wid_letter[i%len(wid_letter)] for i in range(widgets_per_row)}
```

Result would look like this:

```
{1: 'C', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'A', 6: 'B', 7: 'C', 8: 'A', 9: 'B', 10: 'C'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This leads to the same result, is this what you are looking for?

```py
from itertools import cycle

wid_letter = ['C', 'A', 'B']
letter_cycle = cycle(wid_letter)
widgets_per_row = 10

wid_ID_dict = {i: next(letter_cycle) for i in range(1,widgets_per_row+1)}

print(wid_ID_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try：

```
wid_ID_dict = dict(enumerate(wid_letter, start=1))
```

Comment: This does not lead to the same result.

Comment: Please provide commentary as to why this might answer the original poster's question, it will also help subsequent readers of the question to understand why this might work for them.

Comment: It seems to work fine as far as I can see, and gives the same output as the other answers.

Comment: This will not produce the same output when `widgets_per_row` is larger than `wid_letter` is long